# How to switch screens in react native without reloading the page?

Tags: react-native, screen, splash-screen, reload, minimized

I am working on a React Native application and need to change my current screen to splash screen when the app is minimized/inactive. Also when the user goes back to the app again it should go to the last visited page without reloading. How can I do it ? It would be helpful if you guys can share your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get status of [App state](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)

There could be statuses like these

1. `active`
2. `background`
3. `inactive` **IOS** only